# Javascript __doPostBack does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ipad, safari, dopostback

I use __doPostBack in javascript part to filter data when click the filter button.

It works in chrome and IE but not Safari. What is more, It doesnt work in ipad.

The version of safari is 5.1.7

What should I do?

**in javascript part:**

```
var wbePartClientID = "IdOfDiscussionListWebPart";
var filterparameter = 'filterparams';
__doPostBack(wbePartClientID ,filterparameter );
```

**in Code Behind:**

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) 

//safari --> always false
//chrome--> When page load first it is false (normally) and when I click filter button it is "true"
```